# How to select CSS as object

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Dev Tools, in the Elements tab we can see/update the CSS properties of any element.

I know there are several ways to see/copy the color (hex, rgb, hsl).

Is it possible to see/copy a CSS block and copy the properties as a (js) object?

Example:

**Original**

```
color: #0F0,
font-size: 14px
```

**Copyed**

```
color: '#0F0',
fontSize: 14
```

Comment: No. You can probably write a reformatter macro for your IDE.